# Hide Div on Scroll with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm sure this is a trivial problem but I cannot seem to figure it out. I'm trying to fade a side bar in and out, and because I have a few of them in my website, I need to give them individual IDs for Javascript.

This code works

```
$(window).on("scroll", function() {
    var scrollPos = $(window).scrollTop() - 100 ;
    if (scrollPos < 100) {
        $("#menu").fadeOut();
    } else {
        $("#menu").fadeIn();
    }
});
```

This doesn't

```
$(window).on("scroll", function() {
    var menu = document.getElementById("menu");
    var scrollPos = $(window).scrollTop() - 100 ;
    if (scrollPos < 100) {
        menu.fadeOut();
    } else {
        menu.fadeIn();
    }
});
```

In the latter piece, all I'm trying to do is assign a variable.

Here's the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gavinfriel/nhovvj6q/1/

Your help would be appreciated.

Comment: You are mixed javascript and jquery

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to wrap it in a `jQuery` call to make it a `jQuery` object. Otherwise it cannot find the `fadeOut` and `fadeIn` functions:

```
var menu = $("#menu");
```

or

```
var menu = $(document.getElementById("menu"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use jquery to convert menu to jQuery object.
So it will have the fade property

```
$(window).on("scroll", function() {
    var menu = document.getElementById("menu");
    var scrollPos = $(window).scrollTop() - 100 ;
    if (scrollPos < 100) {
        $(menu).fadeOut();
    } else {
        $(menu).fadeIn();
    }
});
```

Because if you use `menu.fadeOut()` it will generate error because `menu`doesn't have `fade` property

Answer (score 0):

Checkout this it will work.

```
 $(window).on("scroll", function() {
    var menu = $("#menu");
        var scrollPos = $(window).scrollTop() - 100 ;
        if (scrollPos < 100) {
            menu.fadeOut();
        } else {
            menu.fadeIn();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, you've declared a JavaScript variable but are trying to use it as a jQuery object.

I would personally go with PierreDuc's answer but if you refactor your code slightly you can carry on using the vanilla JS declared vaiable, but pass the variable slightly differently:

```js
var test = document.getElementById("test");
$(test).hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test">
  TEST
</div>
```

In your 2nd code, this might look as follows:

```
$(window).on("scroll", function() {
    var menu = document.getElementById("menu");
    var scrollPos = $(window).scrollTop() - 100 ;
    if (scrollPos < 100) {
        $(menu).fadeOut();
    } else {
        $(menu).fadeIn();
    }
});
```